# django admin: how to write a reusable class e.g. Address for admin

Tags: django, django-admin

say, we are making a site where customers (`Customer`) can come and rate publishing houses (`PublishingHouse`). We need to store address of both `Customer` and `PublishingHouse`, so we make an `Address` class like this:

```
class Address(models.Model):
  line1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  line2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
  country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and then our `Customer` and `PublishingHouse` class have references to it, like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

class PublishingHouse(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  website = models.URLField(max_length=4096)
  address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

this works fine for my interactive sessions in django shell, but when I activate admin for these models, is there a way that I could make fields from `Address` appear on Add Customer or Add Publishing House page?

I am using django 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [generic inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline). As per the documented [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline) `Address` would be your `Image` model

As per your comment, you could using class inheritance:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    # fields

class DynamicAddress(Address):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    # etc
```

Also you can limit (generic)inlines with the `max_num` attribute on your generic inline admin class.

Comment: thank you, one more question, is there a way I can ensure the relationship between `Address` and other models remains one to one?

Comment: came back to say that I did that. it worked for admin. but wait till you start writing the views (or an API that needs to query the db and return data) and GFKs become too painful. I'd rather stick to normal relations than go for GFKs. @Hedde's answer is correct but not the best way to make fields of a model appear on multiple pages.